# How do I split multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I would like to split each of columns in dataset.

The idea is  to split the number between "/" and string between "/" and "@" and put this values to the new colums.

I tried sth like this :

```
new_df = dane['1: Brandenburg'].str.split('/',1)
```

and then creating new columns for it. But I don't want to do this for all 60 colums.

```
first column

1: Branburg :
ES-NL-10096/1938/X1@hkzydzon.dk/6749
BE-BR-6986/3551/B1@oqk.bf/39927
PH-SA-39552610/2436/A1@venagi.hr/80578
PA-AE-59691/4881/X1@zhicksl.cl/25247 

second column 

2: Achon :
DE-JP-20082/2066/A2@qwier.cu/68849
NL-LK-02276/2136/A1@ozmdpfts.de/73198
OM-PH-313/3671/Z1@jtqy.ml/52408
AE-ID-9632/3806/C3@lhbt.ar/83484

etc,etc...
```

Comment: Since `split` returns a list, what is your expected output? I’m also not sure that I completely understand your explanation of what it is you want to parse.

Comment: is that your dataset?

Comment: Perhaps you want to stack your columns, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html.

Comment: I would like to have a column (list ) with values that  I've splited from origin column. F.e : ```1938 ,3551,2436 next to ES-NL-10096/1938/X1@hkzydzon.dk/6749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you want to extract **two parts** from each cell.
E.g. from *ES-NL-10096/1938/X1@hkzydzon.dk/6749* there should be
extracted:

- *1938* - the number between slashes,
- *X1* - the string between the second slash and *@*.

To to this, you can run:

```
df.stack().str.extract(r'/(?P<num>\d+)/(?P<txt>[A-Z\d]+)@')\
    .stack().unstack([1, 2])
```

You will get a MultiIndex on columns:

- top level - the name of "source" column,
- second level - *num* and *txt* - 2 extracted "parts".

For your sample data, the result is:

```
  1: Brandenburg     2: Achon    
             num txt      num txt
0           1938  X1     2066  A2
1           3551  B1     2136  A1
2           2436  A1     3671  Z1
3           4881  X1     3806  C3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.apply()` to iterate over all the columns of your Dataframe and apply given function. Here is an example:

```
def fn(col):
    return col.str.split('/',1)

new_df = dane.apply (lambda col: fn(col), axis=1)
```

Here `axis=1` means iterate over all the columns. Hope this helps!

Comment: If your `apply` is iterating over columns, why name the input variable `row`? Isn’t that a bit confusing?